# How to create a background application using UWP without UI?

Tags: c#, uwp, bluetooth-lowenergy

I need to run a `BLE` Discovery in background and need to show toast when a device found.This is done using `UWP` with `UI`. But I need only background application. Is there any way?

Comment: Add some code snippets and further information

Comment: I need to know whether it is possible or not to make background task without UI in Windows 10

Comment: Background tasks are possible in any Windows. background tasks in UWP are possible, they are registered when the application starts. You can create an application without adding any view. Don't expect MSFT to approve it on the store though. If you want to know *how*, you will need to explain where exactly your problem is at :)

Comment: Even register the background task without UI? It is impossible.

Comment: @NahuelIanni Please give in detail How I can create an application without any UI. My Exact problem is that I need to run my aplication without any UI and if  a BLE device comes in range, it should show a Toast. All the functionalities are done by using UWP App. But I am not able to do without any view.

Comment: You can register the background task with UI one time, after that the background task can run without UI. But you cannot even register the background task  without UI.

Comment: Please look for Detailed Answer for the above Question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38819116/how-do-you-get-a-ble-advertisment-callback-in-a-desktop-net-app?noredirect=1&lq=1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly I think that it is good to clarify that even if you want to create UWP app that works in background you have to create normal Universal Windows Application from template in Visual Studio:

[image]

Each UWP application can register Background Task to perform some background operations.

You can find the whole implementation guide under below link:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/launch-resume/create-and-register-a-background-task

Background task has to be registered by the app so there is no way to create only Background task without the app.
Please also remember that application without UI will not pass Windows Store certification.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, I need it to work as a background app. There should be no UI. :(

Comment: Right now it is not possible unfortunately.

Comment: Could you suggest me any workaround for the following: Need to Enumerate BLE Devices. When a specific device found it should show a popup to pair the device. All other time it should work as a background application.

Thanks :)

Comment: Yes, I have written code in a DLL( Universal Windows)

Comment: [GattCharacteristicNotificationTrigger](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.applicationmodel.background.gattcharacteristicnotificationtrigger) may help you.

Answer (score 1):

Lukmanul Hakim,

I have been facing a similar problem and found the best way is through a windows service. In particular:

- BluetoothLEAdvertisementWatcher works in Windows services, unit test projects, and UWP packages (with the right manifest capabilities).
- The advertisment watcher executes but does not deliver data/events in WPF desktop apps and .net command line programs.
- As you note, UWP seems to require annoying UI and can only communicate in a limited way via app services.
- Once you have the data in a windows service, you can do work there or communicate with any desktop app using regular IPC mechanisms like named pipes.
- You will need to install the Windows 10 SDK and reference the windows runtime typically at:  C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\UnionMetadata\Windows.winmd

For reference here is the basic code to get advertisments:

```
 var watcher = new BluetoothLEAdvertisementWatcher(); 
 watcher.Received += OnAdvertismentReceived;                      
 watcher.Start();
```

Comment: Did some more research on a related problem, if you include the right WindowsRuntime dll you should be able to use any regular desktop app. [link]http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38819116/how-do-you-get-a-ble-advertisment-callback-in-a-desktop-net-app

Comment: Could you please give me in detail. I am new to Windows applications. In what are the steps to do so. I have BLE Enumeration code with me. Please help me. I think you can help me in this scenario.

My Skype ID: lookzlook

Comment: Thanks David. I got a solution from the link you posted. Thank you so much